# When trying "Run user flow" in Azure ADB2C on Azure platform it throws: "OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler: message.State is null or empty"

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I created .NET8 Web app using Azure ADB2c authorization based on this tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-web-app?tabs=visual-studio

Log-in, log-out, showing claims works nicely both when I run it locally in Visual Studio as well as after deploying it on Azure Services.

[image]

However, when in Azure portal I go to: "ADB2C -> User flows" and click on "Run user flow" and then select "Reply URL" corresponding to version deployed on Azure Service

[image]

it redirect me to login page but when I fill in email + password and click "sign in" button application displays an error:

"OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler: message.State is null or empty."

[image]

Configuration:

Reply URL in ADB2C:

https://adb2clogin23121979webapp.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc

App URL:

https://adb2clogin23121979webapp.azurewebsites.net/

application.json:

```
{
  "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://contosoorg23121979.b2clogin.com",
    "ClientId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "Domain": "contosoorg23121979.onmicrosoft.com",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout/B2C_1_SingInUp",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_SingInUp",
    "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "B2C_1_ResetPassword",
    "EditProfilePolicyId": "B2C_1_ProfileEdit"
  }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
        options.HandleSameSiteCookieCompatibility();
    });

    services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration, Constants.AzureAdB2C);

    services.AddControllersWithViews().AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

    services.AddRazorPages();

    services.AddOptions();
    services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C"));
}
```